# How to change the position of axis label in ggplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

as you can see on my x-axis, I need to move the position of the axis label "5 to 9" together with its bar column in front, after "0 to 4". Below is my code.
[image]

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(age, aes(factor(age), case, fill = sex)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")+
  ylab("# Cases") +
  xlab("Age") +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 13)) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 14))
```

Comment: Please `dput(age)` and add to the post!

Comment: It's right where it "should" be: because those labels are all strings, they are being sorted alphabetically (without regard to numeric content). Use a `factor` to force the order, and `ggplot2` will do what you want. (There are plenty of questions on SO about reordering labels or facets or what-have-you ... and they all end up recommending `factor` and manually controlling the `levels=` of them.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this on your data frame (Age?):

```
library(tidyverse)

Age <- Age %>% 
  mutate(age  = fct_relevel(age, "0 to 4", "5 to 9", "10 to 14"))
```

..but it is possible that you have to take ap all your levels in this list, so it may be not ideal

Comment: thank you,I actually tried this and it works!